# How to retrieve rows with group count > 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, window-functions

I want to retrieve all the rows which the count of a group > 1 without subquery. If subquery used, it will be

```
SELECT *
FROM abc
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT a, COUNT(*) AS cnt
     FROM abc
     GROUP BY a
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) aa 
ON abc.a = aa.a
WHERE aa.a IS NOT NULL
```

Here is the table:

```
|a|b|
|-|-|
|1|2|
|1|3|
|2|3|
|2|4|
|3|3|
|4|4|
```

The result would be

```
|a|b|
|-|-|
|1|2|
|1|3|
|2|3|
|2|4|
```

Comment: Homework / interview question?

Comment: @Alex No. Since I use subquery very often, too often. That's why I ask for a simpler solution.

Comment: So how come your join is missing the join condition? Why not use window functions?

Comment: By having the where clause `WHERE aa.a IS NOT NULL`, you are effectively turning the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. You might as well use `INNER JOIN` and remove the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 2):

An approach that I often use in such cases is a self join.  Something along these lines:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM abc a
INNER JOIN abc b ON a.a = b.a
WHERE a.b <> b.b;
```

It has the advantage of being eminently readable, and usually considerably quicker to type than a query with sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

Just use window functions!

```
select a, b
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by a) cnt
    from abc t
) t
where cnt > 1
```

The window count partitions the dataset by `a`, then counts the overall number of records in the current partition. We can then use this information to filter the dataset.

Comment: The OP specifically did not want to use a sub-query.

Comment: I suspect that what OP wants to avoid is to re-open the same table in a subquery, which seems like a relevant concern as regard to performance - and I would argue that the self-join solution does not avoid re-scanning the table. Conversely, the window function solution scans the table only once; the "subquery" is just a syntactical sugar, since SQL Server does not support the standard `QUALIFY` clause - but the table is scanned just once, @JonathanWillcock.